# Publish imagepyramid on GeoServer SRS "unknown"

Tags: geoserver, image-pyramids

I want to publish an ImagePyramid created by GDAL.

```
gdal_retile.bat -v -r bilinear -levels 4 -ps 2048 2048 -s_srs "+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs" -co "TILED=YES" -co "COMPRESS=JPEG" -targetDir "C:/Temp/pyramid/result" ‪"C:/Temp/pyramid/image.ecw"
```

After adding the imagePyrimid source to GeoServer a shapefile is generated. A grid with image directory. If I add it to QGIS it is placed correctly but in GeoServer the native SRS in GeoServer is "unknown" so I fail to properly publish it.

I have followed the tutorial on geoserver.org as closely as possible.
https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/imagepyramid/imagepyramid.html

I tried to explicitly specify the source srs_def without luck. I also tried without the -s_srs tag.
Is there something obvious I am missing here? I wonder why QGIS handles the coordinate system okay, when GeoServer struggles a bit.

Comment: You can just set the Declared SRS to the correct EPSG code

Comment: hmm geoserver did not like that. When I preview the layer GS crashed and then I found java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded. Now it wont start up again (Tomcat9)

Comment: Got it to work eventually. After the grid shp files were created I changed the proj file by replacing the proj definition in the files (for each pyramid level) with the WKT definition of my projection found here https://epsg.io/. After publishing the layer again, geoserver picked up the correct native projection.